# Prevent local admin from installing any blacklisted package on Ubuntu (Desktop)

Tags: 20.04, package-management, sudo, security

At our company there is a need for Ubuntu clients. However there are some issues regarding security. In our case, most Ubuntu users are local admin (listed in /etc/sudoers) but we would like to prevent users from accessing malicious tools and packages. Currently this is partially performed using Cisco Umbrella / OpenDNS however, it is not fully waterproof.

So how can we make sure security updates and updates to installed packages are executed but users are not able to install 'new' packages or create packages from source?

- Blacklisting packages would solve some of the issues however a local admin could bypass this. Can this be prevented?
- Might there be an interim solution like a privilege level between 'sudoers' and 'generic' users?

Comment: "Convenience" and "safety" are at odds more often than not. While it may be convenient to have some many "admins", it certainly isn't safe.

Comment: You seem to be saying "I have admins that I can't trust" and/or "I have admins who need additional training". Lots of complex and expensive commercial tools to patch over those personnel problems. However, they are fundamentally personnel problems: Admins who cannot be trusted should not be admins. Admins who need training should be trained and re-trained.

Comment: Lets say we have some developers at our place. They require some applications like Fiddler / Wireshark for debugging. They might need some specific packages for their applications. However, we would like to prevent these users to download the newest release of Ubuntu or remove the enterprise virusscan application.

Answer (score 0):

Remove sudo rights from all nasty users and instead use a sudo whitelist for specific commands/users.

Read `man sudoers` and you may read this tutorial *"Run only Specific Commands with sudo in Linux"*: https://kifarunix.com/run-only-specific-commands-with-sudo-in-linux/

Comment: I will look into this. This might be an answer to my second part of my question.

Comment: You should never allow people to be admins when they are clearly not trustworthy. It's a big security leak and it messes also up your work.